# "Подсудимый" - только субстантивированное прилагательное? А страдательным причастием может быть?

Tags: пунктуация, приложение

> ...Должностные лица, которые управляли провинциями от имени императора
>   или сената и которым вверено было исключительное право суда над
>   уголовными преступниками, большей частью вели себя как люди
>   благовоспитанные и образованные, уважающие требования справедливости и
>   знакомые с принципами философии. Нередко случалось, что они отклоняли
>   от себя отвратительную роль гонителей, с презрением отвергали
>   обвинение или научали **подсудимых христиан** какой-нибудь легальной
>   увёртке, с помощью которой можно было избежать строгости законов.
>   Всякий раз, когда они бывали облечены неограниченной властью, они
>   употребляли её не столько на угнетение, сколько на облегчение и пользу
>   страждущей церкви.

Дефиса очень хочется...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В словаре такого значения нет, но в текстах страдательное причастие встречается:

В то время адвокаты обычно не брались защищать **подсудимых** верующих...http://mirboga.mirtesen.ru/blog/43042566850/Mozhet-li-hristianin-obraschatsya-v-sud-Etot-vopros-ya,-pozhaluy